# Prevent rails from changing controller part of url, when post fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a sessions controller, with :new, :create and :delete actions. I also have a method that checks the current page controller:

```
def controller_for(path)
  Rails.application.routes.recognize_path(path)[:controller]
end
```

Normally, this method works fine, but if the user visits `/login` and signs-in with incorrect login details, then rails changes the url to `/sessions` and renders the `:new` action, at which point my method above throws an arror

```
No route matches "/sessions"
```

It seems that `recognize_path` is trying to do this:

```
>> r = Rails.application.routes
>> r.recognize_path "/sessions"
=> {:controller=>"sessions", :action=>"index"}
```

Since I don't have an index action, it is causing an error. What I really want, is this:

```
>> r.recognize_path "/login"
=> {:controller=>"sessions", :action=>"new"}
```

So how can I force rails to keep the url as `/login` when sign-in fails, instead of changing it to `/sessions`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are using restful routes. When you post the login form, you're 'creating' a session, which is achieved by POSTing to /sessions. This is directed to `SessionsController#create`. /login is a separate, custom, non-restful path which gets sent to `SessionsController#new`, basically an alias for /sessions/new.

`recognize_path` defaults to interpreting the path as a GET request when the environment doesn't tell it otherwise. And a GET request assumes `/sessions` to mean the index view.

```
# The recognize_path method in the Rails source:
def recognize_path(path, environment = {})
  method = (environment[:method] || "GET").to_s.upcase
  ...
end
```

One way to 'fix' this is to change your routing. For example, you could add this to your routes:

```
match "/process_login" => "sessions#create", :as => 'process_login'
```

And then change your login form to match:

```
<% form_tag process_login_path do %>
  [your login form here]
<% end -%>
```

Now you'll post the form to /process_login instead of /sessions, and the path should be interpreted properly by the recognizer.

Comment: Thanks, just noticed someone had answered this :) Good info there, I understand it now.

Comment: Glad it was useful. I lose track of my Stack replies from time to time as well ;)